# Does replication run "Create Temporary Table" command in all members of replica?

Tags: mysql, replication

I wanted to create a temporary table in MySQL database which is a member of Master-Master replication. I run the query and created the temporary table, however, the table was created in one of the servers and has not been created in the other member of replication.
My question is, should not all of the queries be run in both of the replication members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not at all.

Quoting the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html):

> A TEMPORARY table is visible only within the current session, and is dropped automatically when the session is closed.

This means, even when you open another connection on the same server, you won't see the table.

Therefore it wouldn't make sense to create the temporary table on multiple servers, at least when you don't use it in a DML statement.

If you use this table to do an UPDATE, DELETE or INSERT statement, it gets replicated, but it depends on the way you replicate.

If your binlog format is STATEMENT, your temporary table is created on disk on the replicating server in the directory you specified in your tmp_data variable.
If it's MIXED or ROW, it gets transmitted in ROW format, if I remember correctly.